# Segmentation fault when array exceeds roughly 255000 int

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to find all the primes smaller than a certain number. Once my list of primes gets above around 255000 primes I get the error "Segmentation fault: 11". Activity Monitor says my process is only using 1.2MB. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int N;
    int arraySize = 1;
    int *primes = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    int isPrime = 1;
    primes[0] = 2;
    int timesRealloc = 0;
    int availableSlots = 100;

    printf("Please enter the largest number you want checked: \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 3; i <= N; i++){ 
        j = 0;
        isPrime = 1;
        while (primes[j] <= sqrt(i)) {
            if (i%primes[j] == 0) {
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (isPrime == 1){
            primes[arraySize] = i;
            arraySize++;
            availableSlots = availableSlots - 1;
        }
        if (availableSlots == 0){
            timesRealloc++;
            availableSlots = 100;
            primes = realloc(primes, 100*sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    /*
    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        printf("%d\n", primes[i]);
    }
    */
    printf("process ID is %d\n", getpid());
    printf("I found %d primes\n", arraySize);
    printf("Memory was reallocated %d times\n", timesRealloc);
    printf("The largest prime I found was %d\n", primes[(arraySize-1)]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have only allocated space for 100 primes with `int *primes = malloc(100*sizeof(int));`

Comment: You never increase the size of the array. It looks like `realloc` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Two easy optimizations.  Your `for` loop can increment `i` by 2 on each iteration instead of by 1. Also, you can stop at sqrt(N) instead of `N`.  `nq = (int)sqrt(N); for (i = 3; i < nq; i+=2`)

Comment: Even when you are reallocating, you use 100 as parameter. I think you should use 100*timesRealloc as the parameter

Answer (score 3):

As it was said in remarks you go out of the array *primes*

Here the code with the minimal number of modifications to run well :

```
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int N;
    int arraySize = 1;
    int *primes = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
    int isPrime = 1;
    primes[0] = 2;
    int timesRealloc = 0;
    int availableSlots = 100;

    printf("Please enter the largest number you want checked: \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 3; i <= N; i++){ 
        j = 0;
        isPrime = 1;
        while (primes[j] <= sqrt(i)) {
            if (i%primes[j] == 0) {
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (isPrime == 1){
            primes[arraySize] = i;
            arraySize++;
         /* LINE REMOVED */
        }
        if (arraySize == availableSlots){ /* MODIFIED */
            timesRealloc++;
            availableSlots += 100; /* MODIFIED */
            primes = realloc(primes, availableSlots*sizeof(int)); /* MODIFIED */
        }
    }

    /*
    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        printf("%d\n", primes[i]);
    }
    */
    printf("process ID is %d\n", getpid());
    printf("I found %d primes\n", arraySize);
    printf("Memory was reallocated %d times\n", timesRealloc);
    printf("The largest prime I found was %d\n", primes[(arraySize-1)]);


    return 0;
}
```

The changes are indicated by a comment

For me *arraySize* must be renamed like *numberOfPrimes*, and *availableSlots* must be renamed *arraySize*

---

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra p.c -lm
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please enter the largest number you want checked: 
500000
process ID is 6337
I found 41538 primes
Memory was reallocated 415 times
The largest prime I found was 499979
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==6354== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6354== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6354== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6354== Command: ./a.out
==6354== 
1000
Please enter the largest number you want checked: 
process ID is 6354
I found 168 primes
Memory was reallocated 1 times
The largest prime I found was 997
==6354== 
==6354== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6354==     in use at exit: 800 bytes in 1 blocks
==6354==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 3,248 bytes allocated
==6354== 
==6354== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6354==    definitely lost: 800 bytes in 1 blocks
==6354==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6354==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6354==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6354==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6354== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6354== 
==6354== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6354== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

*primes* must be free at the end to not have memory leaks

---

Is just a detail but the behavior is not the expected one when entering 1

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please enter the largest number you want checked: 
1
process ID is 6388
I found 1 primes
Memory was reallocated 0 times
The largest prime I found was 2
```

2 is greater than 1 ;-)

This is because you force the presence of 2 (`primes[0] = 2;` etc)

Comment: 1 isn't prime, so presumably you'd start with 2.

Comment: @tadman yes the OP does, but there is no reason to manage 2 as a special case, it can be found as the other prime numbers

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues here.

First, you're not reallocating as much space as you think you are.  You do the initial allocation here:

```
int *primes = malloc(100*sizeof(int));
```

Then reallocate here:

```
primes = realloc(primes, 100*sizeof(int));
```

The amount of space you're reallocating is the same as the original size.  You're not making the array any bigger.  You can fix this by keeping track of the current capacity and increasing it as needed.  So the initial allocation would look like this:

```
int capacity = 100;
int *primes = malloc(capacity*sizeof(int));
```

And the reallocation like this:

```
timesRealloc++;
availableSlots = 100;
capacity += availableSlots;
primes = realloc(primes, capacity*sizeof(int));
```

The second issue is that you start `arraySize` at 1 and write to `primes[arraySize]`, but `availableSlots` is initilaized to 100.  So when you hit the current capacity you're actually writing to one element past the end.

Initialize `availableSlots` to 99 instead of 10:

```
int availableSlots = 99;
```

Also, don't forget to `free(primes)` at the end so you don't have a memory leak.